# $Xml->children() is not working with :commons tag

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

```
   <listing> 
<Community>
            <commons:Subdivision commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Cheat Crossings</commons:Subdivision>
            <commons:Schools>
                <commons:School>
                    <commons:Name>Valley View</commons:Name>
                    <commons:SchoolCategory>Elementary</commons:SchoolCategory>
                    <commons:District commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Monongalia</commons:District>
                    <commons:Description>true</commons:Description>
                </commons:School>
                <commons:School>
                    <commons:Name>MHS</commons:Name>
                    <commons:SchoolCategory>High</commons:SchoolCategory>
                    <commons:District commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Monongalia</commons:District>
                    <commons:Description>true</commons:Description>
                </commons:School>
                <commons:School>
                    <commons:Name>Morgantown Jr High School</commons:Name>
                    <commons:SchoolCategory>JuniorHigh</commons:SchoolCategory>
                    <commons:District commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Monongalia</commons:District>
                    <commons:Description>true</commons:Description>
                </commons:School>
                <commons:School>
                    <commons:Name>South</commons:Name>
                    <commons:SchoolCategory>Middle</commons:SchoolCategory>
                    <commons:District commons:isgSecurityClass="Public">Monongalia</commons:District>
                    <commons:Description>true</commons:Description>
                </commons:School>
            </commons:Schools>
        </Community>
```

How can i get all records of school under schools tag? 
I tried this but it's not working.
$eachListing->Community->Schools->children("commons",true);

Comment: What are you using to parse the xml (simpleXML or DOMDocument)?

Comment: i am using simpleXML

Comment: Can you show the definition for the `commons` namespace?

Comment: No i don't have. all that i have that xml and the type is "xs:string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here should be a xmlns:commons="..." attribute somewhere. The value of this attribute is the actual namespace, the 'common' prefix is just an alias for it. Define a variable or constant in your application with the namespace and use it, not the alias/prefix.

```
const XMLNS_COMMON = 'http://rets.org/xsd/RETSCommons'; // the value from the xmlns:common attribute?
$eachListing->Community->Schools->children(XMLNS_COMMON);
```

The alias/prefix can be changed on each node in a document and is not mandatory. Do not base your logic on it.

It might be necessary to do this on for any node that is not in the namespace of the document element.

```
$nodes = $eachListing
  ->Community
  ->children(XMLNS_COMMON)->Schools
  ->children(XMLNS_COMMON);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/205950

Comment: sorry it's not working in my end. i used simplexml_load_file method and the error is "node no longer exist" and when i use simplexml_load_string,the error is Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found.

Comment: simplexml_load_string() loads from a xml string, simplexml_load_file() loads from an file. Did you notice that the demo uses the children() method for each node in the namespace?

Comment: yes i noticed. But it throw me this error "node no longer exist" whenever i tried. my code is 
$nodes = $eachListing
  ->Community
  ->children(XMLNS_COMMON)->Schools
  ->children(XMLNS_COMMON);

var_dump($nodes);