# Extract XML feed to PHP to insert in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

If I try to insert everything to the database everything works, only things which don't work are the content:encoded because it has :encoded I wanna insert all the data correctly in the fields I currently have. The XML data is news articles, I need to insert into a new database.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.azned.nl/feed.xml");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$indexFeed = simplexml_load_string($response);   
$indexFeed = str_replace("<content:encoded>","<contentEncoded>", $response);
$indexFeed = str_replace("</content:encoded>","</contentEncoded>", $response);
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {

$obj = $modx->newObject('modResource', array(
'pagetitle'             => $entry->pagetitle,
'description'           => $entry->description,
'content'               => $entry->contentEncoded,
'type'                  => 'document',
'longtitle'             => $entry->longtitle,
'link'                  => $entry->link,
'published'             => 1,
'pub_date'              => 0,
'alias'                 => $entry->pagetitle, $entry->longtitle,
'parent'                => 2,
'folder'                => 0,
'richtext'              => 1,
'template'              => 2,
'menuindex'             => 3,
'searchable'            => 1,
'cacheable'             => 1,
'createdby'             => 6,
'editedon'              => 6,
'editedby'              => 6,
'deleted'               => 0,
'deletedon'             => 0,
'deletedby'             => 0,
'publishedby'           => 6,
'donthit'               => 0,
'privateweb'            => 0,
'privatemgr'            => 0,
'content_dispo'         => 0,
'hidemnu'               => 0,
'class_key'             => 'Article',
'context_key'           => 'web',
'content_type'          => 1,
'uri_override'          => 1,
'hide_children_in_tree' => 0,
'show_in_tree'          => 0,
'properties'            => 'Properties'
));
```

Comment: this seems to be a problem with a non escaped field in your query... can you show the code you are using to save the data in your database ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I use Modx, and the query is corect. It just doesn't go through the right way

`if(!$obj->save()) 
        $modx->log(modx::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, print_r('Failed to save',1));
    else
        $modx->log(modx::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, print_r('Success',1));`

Comment: What is the right way??? Yo have no problem with saving data into DB right? So whats your problem. but parse your data into string `(string)$entry->contentEncoded,` this is good if you do. And if you what to extract data of child node having `:child` then use `define("XMLNS_COMMON", "http://rets.org/xsd/RETSCommons");` on top and to get data use `(string)$obj->content->children(XMLNS_COMMON)->encoded` ......something like that. see this link might help ou i think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366925/xml-children-is-not-working-with-commons-tag
and instead of `common` find out yours.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.

This is the error I currently get "PHP warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"